# Changing variable value inside golang switch statement

Tags: go, switch-statement

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i int = 10
    switch true {
    case i < 20:
        fmt.Printf("%v is less than 20\n", i)
        i = 100
        fallthrough
    case i < 19:
        fmt.Printf("%v is less than 19\n", i)
        fallthrough
    case i < 18:
        fmt.Printf("%v is less than 18\n", i)
        fallthrough
    case i > 50:
        fmt.Printf("%v is greater than 50\n", i)
        fallthrough
    case i < 19:
        fmt.Printf("%v is less than 19\n", i)
        fallthrough
    case i == 100:
        fmt.Printf("%v is equal to 100\n", i)
        fallthrough
    case i < 17:
        fmt.Printf("%v is less than 17\n", i)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10 is less than 20
100 is less than 19
100 is less than 18
100 is greater than 50
100 is less than 19
100 is equal to 100
100 is less than 17
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Yes it is. Please explain why do you think it's not.

Comment: That is the expected behavior of `fallthrough` per the language specification. What is your expectation? - https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements (under Expression switches)

Comment: `fmt.Println("1 equals 0")` prints `1 equals 0` and yes, that is expected behaviour.

Comment: My expectation was when I change value of "i" in first expression it will be evaluated in next "case".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`fallthrough`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Fallthrough_statements) statement transfers control to the first statement of the next `case` block.

The `fallthrough` statement **does not** mean to continue evaluating the expression of the next `case`, but to unconditionally start executing the next `case` block.

Quoting from `fallthrough` statement doc:

> A "fallthrough" statement transfers control to the first statement of the next case clause in an expression "switch" statement.

Quoting from [`switch` statement doc](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements):

> In a case or default clause, the last non-empty statement may be a (possibly [labeled](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Labeled_statements)) ["fallthrough" statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Fallthrough_statements) to indicate that control should flow from the end of this clause to the first statement of the next clause. Otherwise control flows to the end of the "switch" statement.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.

Anyway, wouldn't it be great if it was evaluated in next "case" ?
Why should it not be evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, as pointed by icza.

If you don't want to fall under every case block after first, remove `fallthrough` lines (it's like you wouldn't have put a `break` line at the end of each C/C++ case block.

And, as you expect in comments, the evaluation is done when `switch()` is reached, after that it doesn't matter if you change `i` value, it won't be evaluated again on each case block.